# Achievements notification is not working in Mobile App

Tags: discussion, android-app

In the morning I open Stack Overflow in a browser, and it's saw me all achievements. See the snap below.

[image]

But when I open the Stack Exchange mobile app, it's saw me nothing. See the snap below.

[image]

Comment: You mean nothing happens when you click that button in the Android app ?

Comment: No when i clicked it's saw me all the activity but as per the snap it's not saw me Badge count in Green color

Comment: The green [+20] notification you see in the top bar ? The android app doesn't have that. Maybe make this a [feature-request] ?

Comment: ok i don't know about this but it's saw me that count when i open SO in mobile Browser.

Comment: Related: [Recent achievements & Recent inbox messages not shown on Android app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253814) and [Optional Android notifications for reputation changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202512).

Comment: What does *"it's saw me nothing"* and *"saw me all achievements"* mean?